# Get entity from Repository and if it is null create new one in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

`Currency` entity that I get by id from Repository may be null. In this case I want to create new `Currency` entity with this id and then persist it again.

I have come with below solution

```
    Optional<Currency> currencyOptional = currencyRepository.findById(1L);
    Currency usd;
    if (currencyOptional.isEmpty()) {
        usd = Currency.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .currencyCode(ECurrencyCode.USD)
                .rates(new HashSet<>())
                .build();
    } else {
        usd = currencyOptional.get();
    }
```

Are there any solution better than this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Currency usd = currencyRepository.findById(1L).orElse(
            Currency.builder()
                    .id(1L)
                    .currencyCode(ECurrencyCode.USD)
                    .rates(new HashSet<>())
                    .build());
```